# Java getIntent problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am new to java programming and im currently trying to pass over info to another class and display it as a TextView. I have two classes: Match and MatchResult. In Match you can push a button and a int will +1. I also have a button on the site which can make you go to the next class. In the next class i want do make the score get displayed in a TextView. But something isn't working and I don't understand why. Here is my code hope someone can help me:

Match.java:

```
    public class Match extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
TextView awayGoals, homeGoals, home, away;
Button homebtn, awaybtn, gotoresult;
int homecount, awaycount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match);

    baconAndEggs();

    homebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    awaybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    gotoresult.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void sendInfo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Match.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, awaycount);
    Intent homeintent = new Intent(this, Match.class);
    homeintent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, homecount);
}



private void baconAndEggs() {
    awayGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Away);
    homeGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Home);
    homebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);
    awaybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.awayBtn);
    gotoresult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.matchResult);

}

public void counter() {
    awaycount = 1;
    homecount = 0;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.homeBtn:
        homecount ++;
        homeGoals.setText("Lakers: " + homecount);
        break;
    case R.id.awayBtn:
        awaycount ++;
        awayGoals.setText("Heat: " + awaycount);
        break;
    case R.id.matchResult:
        Intent result = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        startActivity(result);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

MatchResult.java:

```
    public class MatchResult extends Activity {

TextView home, away;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match_result);

    resultcounter();

    Intent awayintent = getIntent();
    String awayresult = awayintent.getStringExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    Intent homeintent = getIntent();
    String homeresult = homeintent.getStringExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    home.setText(homeresult);
    Log.d("Petter", homeresult);
}
```

The Log dosen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding as 'Integer' putExtra("KEY", int) and retrieving as 'String' (getStringExtra)

Change sendInfo with:

```
 public void sendInfo(View view) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount);
   startActivituy(intent);
}
```

Change MatchResult with:

```
 public class MatchResult extends Activity {

TextView home, away;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.match_result);

   resultcounter();

int awayresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, -1);
int homeresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, -1);

home.setText(String.valueOf(homeresult));
Log.d("Petter", String.valueOf(homeresult));
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error on this two lines: int awayresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
int homeresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

The error is "that I need an int"

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the parameter 'defaultValue'..do like this: getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE, -1); as '-1' is the default value..meaning that if the parameter is not available, it will be -1.

Comment: Don't have any error now in the code, but the score is always -1

Comment: then it means that the data wasn't passed correctly..i noticed another problem..the KEYS used by AWAY and HOME must be different..see the update on the answer. Define another key.

Comment: Still dosent work, added my code as a answear so you can see whats wrong

Comment: are you calling it with: Intent intent = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class); ?

Comment: the problem is on the sendInfo() it should be an intent for MatchResult.class, not for Match.class;

Comment: are you sure you're using: Intent intent = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class); on the sendInfo() ?

Comment: I cant find any wrong spellings or anything i have done wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the second Activity using this:

```
case R.id.matchResult:
        Intent result = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        result.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, awaycount);//Use this
        result.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, homecount);//Use this
        startActivity(result);
        break;
```

put an Intent here. Don't use 2 intents. Just put the two variables using 2 keys in same intent.

In second activity do this:

Intent intent = getIntent();
String awayresult = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, -1));
String homeresult = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, -1));

Answer (score 0):

Match:

```
    public class Match extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
TextView awayGoals, homeGoals, home, away;
Button homebtn, awaybtn, gotoresult;
int homecount, awaycount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match);

    baconAndEggs();

    homebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    awaybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    gotoresult.setOnClickListener(this);


}

 public void sendInfo(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
       intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

private void baconAndEggs() {
    awayGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Away);
    homeGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Home);
    homebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);
    awaybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.awayBtn);
    gotoresult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.matchResult);

}

public void counter() {
    awaycount = 1;
    homecount = 0;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.homeBtn:
        homecount++;
        homeGoals.setText("Lakers: " + homecount);
        break;
    case R.id.awayBtn:
        awaycount++;
        awayGoals.setText("Heat: " + awaycount);
        break;
    case R.id.matchResult:
        Intent result = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        startActivity(result);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

MatchResult:

```
public class MatchResult extends Activity {

TextView home, away;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match_result);

    resultcounter();

    int awayresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, -1);
    int homeresult = getIntent().getIntExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, -1);

    home.setText(String.valueOf(homeresult));
    Log.d("Petter", String.valueOf(homeresult));
    away.setText(String.valueOf(awayresult));
}

public void resultcounter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeresult);
    away = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.awayresult);
}
}
```